# datetime saved in database but when i want to call the datetime it is a nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have a `datetime`, called `due_date`, that gets saved in `agreement` table. When i want to display the datetime, it just gives me nil, however Im looking at my db row and its clearly not nil. must be some sort of formating problem.. im using mountain time zone for my whole application as the `datetime` value called `due_date` needs to be my timezone anyways. the reason is my `due_date` is set to the end of the day and i want it to be specifically mountain time.  Im using rails and postgres.

As you can see I have an agreement with the due_date entered.. now when i want to display the due_date value it gives me nil.
[image]

application.rb

```rails
 config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

All in all how can I display `@agreement.due_date` and give me the same date from the db?

- also a note is from the picture is that when i try `@agreement.created_at` it shows up just fine unlike the `due_date`

Comment: did you forget to commit?

Comment: Does your `Agreement` model have an overloaded `due_date` method by any chance? Please, share the model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime retrieval says nil when I see that it was inserted into db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011228/datetime-retrieval-says-nil-when-i-see-that-it-was-inserted-into-db)

Comment: How is this question different from [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44011228/6464308)?

Comment: share the model +1

Comment: It had an overload like mudasobwa said